# Prestashop - Global Kernel PHP

Tags: php, prestashop

Currently upgrading a callback function (costumer pays it works as a webhook) where I was initializing the kernel as a global variable.

```
global $kernel;
    if(!$kernel){ 
      require_once _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/app/AppKernel.php';
      $kernel = new \AppKernel('prod', false);
      $kernel->boot(); 
    }
```

I've tried using this code as it worked before but prestashop new guidelines stop it from being accepted on prestashop validator.
Has anyone been able to workaround this issue?

Comment: Are you facing any error message? Using global variables causes many problems, and that's why you're warned to do to it since years